# How do I supress the background plot for a multi-panel plot?

Tags: r

I want to make a multi-panel plot, with a map in background & then add points. But the background plot is always plotted separately first, which i would like to avoid.

This is my function

```
png(filename = paste0(path_figures, "no2.png"), height = 25, width = 18, units = "cm", res = 1080)

layout(matrix(c(1,2,3,4), byrow = T))

plotAUT = function(Region, Data, Stations, Range, Season, CB = TRUE, ...){
  
  # background map
  plot(map(regions = Region), type="l", ...)
  
  # define colours
  colour = inferno((length(Range)-1))
  
  for (i in 1:length(Data)) {
    C = "white"
    
    if (Season == "DJF"){
    for (j in 1:(length(Range)-1)) {
      if(between(no2_DJF[i], Range[j], Range[j+1], incbounds=TRUE)){
        C = colour[j]
      }else{
        next()
      }
     }
    }
```

*omitted the other else if statements checking for seasons*

```
    # plotting points on map
    points(loc$station_longitude_deg[i], loc$station_latitude_deg[i], pch=21, bg=C, lwd=1.5)
  }

  # add colourbar
  if(CB == TRUE){
    set.colorbar(cbx = c(17.47664, 17.82569), cby = c(46.2940, 49.11994), pal = colour, ticks = Range)
  }else{
    next()
  }
  
}
```

Now if i call the the function i get this output

[multi-panel plot but with the map plotted separately](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gBkIf.png)